# Include Everything in a Directory but one thing

Tags: gruntjs

I want to run grunt-contrib-concat over a directory and match everything in it except for one subdirectory, however, within that subdirectory I want to match one file. So it looks like this:

```
// Include everything
topDir/

// Include only one file in this specific directory
topDir/**/subdir/onlyIncludeThisFromThisDirectory.whatever
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy as:

```
[
  'topDir/**/*.whatevet',
  '!topDir/**/subdir/**/*',
  'topDir/**/subdir/onlyIncludeThisFromThisDirectory.whatever']`
]
```

The pattern  with leading `!` is the [excluding pattern](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).
Remember that you should always include `.extension` to the matching pattern, when using "Files Array" mapping, because pattern `**/*` matches directories too.
To avoid this, you can use dynamic mapping:

```
files: {
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'topDir/',
  src: ['**/*', '!**/subdir/**/*', '**/subdir/onlyIncludeThisFromThisDirectory.whatever'],
  dest: 'dest/',
  filter: 'isFile'
}
```

See [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) for more info.